# Test cases to test a function phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to php unit testing, What are the valid test cases for below function.

```
 protected function validateParams($graph, $start, $destination)
{
    if (!is_object($graph)) {

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Graph param should be an object !');
    }

    if (empty($start)) {

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Start param is empty !');
    }

    if (empty($destination)) {

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Graph param is empty !');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to design test cases in general or how to implement them in PHP?

Comment: I'm asking suitable test cases not to do in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, test that when passing the correct arguments to the method, it returns `true`.

```
public function testParamsValidation();
```

Then check that an `InvalidArgumentException` is thrown when any of the arguments is empty. Note that you should have 3 tests, one for each of the arguments. In each test you pass only one empty argument. You probably want to have each of these tests executed several times with distinct argument values (like null, false, scalars, etc). Use [dataProviders](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) for that.

```
public function testInvalidArgumentExceptionIsThrownWhenGraphIsNotAnObject(;

public function testInvalidArgumentExceptionIsThrownWhenStartIsEmpty();

public function testInvalidArgumentExceptionIsThrownWhenDestinationIsEmpty();
```

Side note: you probably want to explicit the required object class in the method definition. The $graph object should be of a certain class or implement a certain interface?

Comment: can u give some example too ?

Comment: Please study the PHPUnit docs and try implenting the test cases. At least the first one is trivial. If you get stuck post another question and we'll help :-)